# Build an object/ name the keys of an array?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to connect my firebase database with angolia servers. My firebase database is synced to an excel sheet. I asked them for help, and they said:

Your code to "Build an array of all records to push to Algolia" will need to build an object to push into the array. You'll need to name the keys for how you want the data to appear in Algolia.

I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help me?

```
// Get all contacts from Firebase
database.ref('/trips').once('value', contacts => {
  // Build an array of all records to push to Algolia
  const records = [];
  contacts.forEach(contact => {
    // get the key and data from the snapshot
    const childKey = contact.key;
    const childData = contact.val();
    // We set the Algolia objectID as the Firebase .key
    childData.objectID = childKey;
    // Add object for indexing
    records.push(childData);
  });
  // Add or update new objects
  index
    .saveObjects(records)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Contacts imported into Algolia');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error when importing contact into Algolia', error);
      process.exit(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't `contacts` already an array?

Comment: What is the structure of contacts? Can you post a sample output?

Comment: Yes, please add some of the Firebase data to your question. It is possible that you can use it as-is.

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane `contacts` appears to be a [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 contacts.forEach(contact => {
    records.push(contact);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The map method might be useful in this situation.

```
const records = contacts.map(contact => {key: contact.key});
```

Just add the keys that you want to appear in your database.